# Is it possible to give index to a date and then use jumpToPage to that date?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

So this is what I want basicly:
[image]

I want every day to be and index so 2020 jan. is `31 days + feb. 21 = 52`. When I click on feb 21 I want to jump to page with index 52. Right now Its jump to 52 because of this code:

```
controller.jumpToPage(52);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.difference()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html) :

```dart
final firstDate = DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
final secondDate = DateTime(2020, 2, 21);
final index = secondDate.difference(firstDate).inDays;
controller.jumpToPage(index) // index : 51
```

Comment: Thank you, It was pretty helpful so far, but I don’t get it how to use the controller.jumpToPage. If I chose like jan 15 how do I jump to number 15. page?

Comment: @Matelevi12 I don't know what you are referring by `controller.jumpToPage`.

Comment: I am using this:
https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield
Should i use something else?

Comment: What is the `controller` related to ? A `TabView`?

Comment: final controller = new PageController(initialPage: 999);
Then i use:
body: PageView.builder(
          controller: controller,
Then i try to use this:
controller.jumpToPage(index);

Comment: I did it!
 final index = date.difference(firstDate).inDays;
        setState(() {
          controller.jumpToPage(index);

Thank you!